# Generar un array a partir de modelo Eloquent

Tags: json, laravel-5, eloquent, model-view-controller, relaciones

favor me ayudan con lo siguiente que intento hacer

Estoy generando un array a partir del modelo Person, y quiero obtener ademas en ese array los datos de las tablas con las que se relaciona. tengo lo siguiente:

```
return Person::with('user')
    ->with('personposition')
    ->with('area')
    ->where('status','habilitado')
    ->get();
```

Esto anda correctamente, pero también quiero obtener los datos del modelo usuario y los roles (Es una tabla pivote "role_user" pero no se de que forma tendría que hacerlo.

En mi modelo User tengo lo siguiente

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no sé si sea esto exactamente lo que quieres pero puedes acceder a las relaciones de los modelos en el with con un . así:

```
return Person::with('user.roles')
    ->with('personposition')
    ->with('area')
    ->where('status','habilitado')
    ->get();
```

y ya quedaría en el pivot como tal.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero era justo lo que necesitaba